# How to disable aggregation from either drush or PHPmyadmin?

Tags: 8, css-js-aggregation

I've been searching for this and ALL I found deals with Drupal 7. Old drush command `drush vset preprocess_js 0` doesn't work for Drupal 8 and the "variable" table in DB doesn't exist in 8...

Yet, I can't disable aggregation in my D8 site for some reason and want to disable it from either drush or DB.

Do you know a way?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Drupal 8 version to disable aggregation:

## disable CSS/JS aggregation

```
drush -y config-set system.performance css.preprocess 0
drush -y config-set system.performance js.preprocess 0
```

Answer (score 6):

If you need it for your development environment you can enable `settings.local.php` in your `settings.php`

```
if (file_exists($app_root . '/' . $site_path . '/settings.local.php')) {
  include $app_root . '/' . $site_path . '/settings.local.php';
}
```

and than make sure ONLY in your local `settings.local.php` (not on your live enviroment) the following settings are used

```
$config['system.performance']['css']['preprocess'] = FALSE;
$config['system.performance']['js']['preprocess'] = FALSE;
```

**NOTE:** those settings can probably be found in `sites/default.settings.local.php` which you can copy to `sites/default/settings.local.php` and make use of.

Answer (score 3):

Use these commands to unset the CSS and JS aggregation using Drush.

### Drupal 7

```bash
drush vset preprocess_js 0 --yes
drush vset preprocess_css 0 --yes
```

### Drupal 8

Refer above comments.