# CSS not applying in drupal 8 site

Tags: 8, theming

I have upgraded my site from 8.1.3 to 8.4 after that, while i load any pages. CSS is not been applied

[image]

**View source:**

[image]

**while inspecting in browser**

[image]

**Cases tried:** Placed an image file in the (**core/themes/seven**) folder and I can successfully access it from the browser.

Comment: Run database updates, clear the cache.

Comment: @PatrickKenny: I run command  **drush updb** returns it shows No database updates required followed by **drush cr** still the same issue

Answer (score 1):

I have followed this and disabled the [css/js](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/221268/how-to-disable-aggregation-from-either-drush-or-phpmyadmin) aggregation. Css were applied.